# clang error in installing data.table in mac OS high sierra

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio, macos-high-sierra

Hi I have been trying to install data.table from mac high sierra and R studio. I tried the following and I am getting the following error. I tried updating the brew and install xcode. Please suggest how this error can be solved? Thanks so much.

```
    > sessionInfo()
  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
 Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

 Matrix products: default
  BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

 locale:
 [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

     attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

  other attached packages:
   [1] sp_1.3-1

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] compiler_3.5.1  tools_3.5.1     grid_3.5.1     
       [4] lattice_0.20-35

       ## INSTALLATION OF DATA TABLE 
 > install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
  +                  repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
 trying URL 

'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table/src/contrib/data.table_1.11.7.tar.gz'
      Content type 'application/gzip' length 3198790 bytes (3.1 MB)
 ==================================================
 downloaded 3.1 MB

    * installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
    ** libs
  clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
     clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
     make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
        ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
     * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/data.table’
    Warning in install.packages :
     installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: To build from source you need a suitable compiler; [the installation page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) has details.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work, looks like a complex solution